# Adding maximal levels to both factors

Tags: r, levels

I have 2 factors A and B:
Factor A has the following levels:

```
> levels (A)
[1] "1" "2" "3"
```

Whereas factor B has the following levels:

```
> levels (B)
[1] "1" "2"
```

I would like to calculate the proportion of elements for which their levels coincide, so I use the following:

```
C<-mean (A == B)
```

Since they have to be with same level. I added to B the "3" level by:

```
levels(B) <- c(levels(B), "3")
```

However it is just an example, since sometimes A has more levels than B and sometimes B has more levels than A. I would like to insert to each of them the maximal number of levels so they will be the same and I'll be able to calculate C. How can I do it?

Comment: Maybe `levels(B) <- union(levels(A), levels(B))` but I think you will need to show us your vectors and a desired result.  Taking the mean of a factor is a bad idea.

Comment: You can check the length of the `levels` of your vectors and add the missing ones accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to check the proportion of times when the levels of two factors coincide and running into errors when the factors have different level sets; perhaps something like:

```
a <- factor(c("a", "b", "c"))
b <- factor(c("b", "b", "c"))
a == b
# Error in Ops.factor(a, b) : level sets of factors are different
```

Instead of messing with the levels of the factors to get rid of this error, I would simply use `as.character` to grab the names of the levels and then compare:

```
mean(as.character(a) == as.character(b))
# [1] 0.6666667
```